# Date in MySql turns to DateTime in .net

Tags: mysql, datetime, datagridview

I've a DB in MySql, with a field DATE where i store only dates.
When i'm getting this field from DB and put it into DataGridView it adds also default time

for example, if i have 1.1.11 in DB, in DataGridView i see "1.1.11 12:00 AM"

how can i prevent the additional date from being added to the datagridview

Comment: I'm not really a .NET guy, but maybe this will help http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/104258.aspx

Comment: What code is in between the DataGridView and the database? An ORM? Raw SQL?

Comment: didn't understand your question, what does it mean "what code?"
the connection has been made with MySql .Net Connector 6.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle.aspx), which represents a [`DataGridViewCellStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.aspx) which has a [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) property. What basically happens is that on rendering your column, it converts the underlying data to a textual representation, and you have the ability to tell it what format this textual representation will adhere to.

So, you look at what `DateTime` [standard format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [custom format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) looks like, and there you have it (you'll specifically want the [short date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortDate) if I'm not mistaken)!

Example:

```
// Set format to short date
myDataGridView.Columns["datecolumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";
```

**EDIT** (following the announcement that the control in question is in fact a `DataGrid`):

Well, the documentation on MSDN pertaining to `DataGrid`s actually gives you the information you need:

> To format the text of a column, set the Format property of the DataGridTextBoxColumn to one of the values found in Formatting Types and Custom Date and Time Format Strings.

There is a nicely documented example [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.tablestyles.aspx).

Comment: the thing here is that the one who has implemented this part didn't define a columns in grid view, but just populated it with the DataTable, like this

dataGridStatData.DataContext = table.DefaultView;

therefore i cant just edit column style...

Comment: also my mistake, i see that it was implemented with DataGrid control, and not as i stated before DataGridView...